# how to get character code

Tags: vb.net

hello
Is it possible to get character character code in `Visual Basic 2008` and to get character from character code ( **Without form1_keyDown or KeyUp**)?.

What i need is two `functions`, first to get `character code` of a `character`, and second to get `character` from `character code`.

thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/613dxh46%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
Public Function Chr(ByVal CharCode As Integer) As Char
Public Function ChrW(ByVal CharCode As Integer) As Char
```

Answer (score 10):

From Unicode code point (**not**, strictly speaking, ASCII) to character: `Chr` and `ChrW`.

Inverse direction: `Asc` and `AscW`.

To get the character representation in specific encodings you need to use the methods of the [`System.Text.Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) class.